# How the time_point created with different duration(std::chrono::milliseconds and std::chrono::nanoseconds) is so different

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono

I have created `std::chrono::milliseconds ms` and `std::chrono::nanoseconds ns` 
 from `std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()`. From that duration I created `timepoints` and convert it to `time_t` using `system_clock::to_time_t`  and print it using `ctime` function. But the time printed is not same. As I understand the `time_point` have duration and duration have rep and period (ratio). So time_point must have same value up to  millisecond precision in both time_points. Why the output is different?

Here is my code

```
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main ()
{
    std::chrono::milliseconds ms = std::chrono::duration_cast < std::chrono::milliseconds > (std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());

    std::chrono::nanoseconds ns = std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::nanoseconds > (std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());

    std::chrono::duration<unsigned int,std::ratio<1,1000>> today_day (ms.count());

    std::chrono::duration<system_clock::duration::rep,system_clock::duration::period> same_day(ns.count());

    system_clock::time_point abc(today_day);
    system_clock::time_point abc1(same_day);

    std::time_t tt;        

    tt = system_clock::to_time_t ( abc );
    std::cout << "today is: " << ctime(&tt);

    tt = system_clock::to_time_t ( abc1 );
    std::cout << "today is: " << ctime(&tt);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
std::chrono::duration<unsigned int,std::ratio<1,1000>> today_day (ms.count());
```

is overflowing.  The number of milliseconds since 1970 is on the order of 1.5 trillion.  But `unsigned int` (on your platform) overflows at about 4 billion.

Also, depending on your platform, this line:

```
std::chrono::duration<system_clock::duration::rep,system_clock::duration::period> same_day(ns.count());
```

*may* introduce a conversion error.  If you are using gcc, `system_clock::duration` is `nanoseconds`, and there will be no error.

However, if you're using llvm's libc++, `system_clock::duration` is `microseconds` and you will be silently multiplying your duration by 1000.

And if you are using Visual Studio, `system_clock::duration` is `100 nanoseconds` and you will be silently multiplying your duration by 100.

[Here is a video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M) for `<chrono>` which may help, and contains warnings about the use of `.count()` and `.time_since_epoch()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial.

Comment: Sir i hava a question is the time_since_epoch is the duration between reference point(1970-01-01T00:00:00Z) and current UTC time or it is the duration between reference point(1970-01-01T00:00:00Z) and current local time.I guess it is the first one.

Comment: Officially the `system_clock::time_since_epoch()` is unspecified.  However all implementations are measuring the current UTC time since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, _excluding_ leap seconds.  That is, in this measure, every day is exactly 86400 seconds.  This is known as [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  The current C++20 draft specification makes this definition official.

Comment: Why hasn't this tutorial be linked in all the other chrono Q&A threads? Thanks a lot! And now I know, why I see your name on all the (helpful) answers I've been studying today... Wish I could +1 it more than once.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The conversions you do manually do not look right.

You should use `duration_cast` for conversions because they are type-safe:

```
auto today_day = duration_cast<duration<unsigned, std::ratio<86400>>>(ms);
auto same_day = duration_cast<system_clock::duration>(ns);
```

Outputs:

```
today is: Thu Jul 26 01:00:00 2018
today is: Thu Jul 26 13:01:08 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you throw away the duration info, and then interpret an integer value as a different duration type

```
std::chrono::duration<unsigned int,std::ratio<1,1000>> today_day (ms.count());
```

milliseconds -> dimensionless -> 1 / 1000 seconds (i.e. milliseconds)

```
std::chrono::duration<system_clock::duration::rep,system_clock::duration::period> same_day(ns.count());
```

nanoseconds -> dimensionless -> system clocks

You should instead just `duration_cast` again

```
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main ()
{
    milliseconds ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    nanoseconds ns = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());

    system_clock::time_point abc(duration_cast<system_clock::duration>(ms));
    system_clock::time_point abc1(duration_cast<system_clock::duration>(ns));

    std::time_t tt;
    tt = system_clock::to_time_t ( abc );
    std::cout << "today is: " << ctime(&tt);

    tt = system_clock::to_time_t ( abc1 );
    std::cout << "today is: " << ctime(&tt);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I think for my code it will be better it will fail at compile time if i did not pass  system_clock::duration to  system_clock::time_point at constructor.

Comment: @user1438832 why? you can just as easily `duration_cast`

Comment: Yes i got it. But i think it will be better if the code i posted failed at compile time if as i did not pass system_clock::duration to system_clock::time_point at constructor. It can check the rep and period of passed duration is matched with system_clock::duration::rep and system_clock::duration::period if not failed at compile time.